# Select multiple folders from mediaStore

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, mediastore, android-music-player

I'm trying to select multiple folders by querying the mediaStore. I can select a single folder by sing this piece of code:

```
 String[] whereVal;
    String selection;


Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

 selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? " ;
        whereVal = new String[]{"%Folder%"};


    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, whereVal, null);
```

However when I try to select multiple folders mediaStore returns nothing.
Code:

```
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "  IN(?,?)" ;
        whereVal = new String[]{"%Top 20 English%","%Audio%"};

 String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, whereVal, null);
```

Care to help me out? Thank in advance.
PS: I don't want to use OR operator.

Comment: `IN` is not a plural version of `LIKE`

Comment: What do you suggest I do? What changes?

Comment: try using `OR`?

Comment: Right now, I have hardcoded the folder names, but actually I have an array of folder paths, so I guess `OR` is of no use.

Comment: no use? `OR` does not work in sqlite?

Comment: Yeah, it works, but the array is dynamic so, I can't hardcode. If possible can you  post a piece of code?

Comment: By the way, can you tell me what is wrong with my current code>?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XYNjqxmj

Comment: Well, you see in your code `SELECT * FROM test WHERE name="one" OR name="three";` one and three are hardcoded, but I have to get these values from the array, so I guess it is not possible..?

Comment: so simply use question mark - `?`

Comment: So if I have 10 folders, do I have to write 10  `OR` ?

Comment: no, you have to use 9 `OR`

Comment: Yeah, well that the problem, user can add 3,4,..or even 10 folders. So it is totally dynamic. If I use 9 `OR` statements but user adds 20 folders, the app will crash.

Comment: By the way what is IN(?,?,? ) for ?  I read it for this type of situations.

Comment: build your query based on number of folders - something like https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/room/runtime/src/main/java/android/arch/persistence/room/util/StringUtil.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#54 - instead of `"?"` in  `builder.append("?");` append your statement and instead of `","` append `" OR "`

Comment: Well thank you, I'll try.